# Variable is not reflecting update in view when variable is updated in the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app where i'm trying to update a variable in the view using a function.

in my view have:

```
<form ng-controller="ScanCtrl">
    <div ng-click="method()">button</div>
    <p>{{alert}}</p>
    <p>{{working}}</p>
</form>
```

in my controller I have:

```
.controller('ScanCtrl', function($scope, QB){
    $scope.working = 'this update works';
    $scope.method = function(){
        $scope.alert = 'this one doesn't';
    }; 
});
```

The "working" variable is updated correctly, but if clicked the `div`, `alert` doesn't seem to be updated in the view.

I tried $scope.apply and it throws an error.

Here is the full code of the controller:

```
nojquery

.controller('ScanCtrl', function($scope, QB){
    $scope.scan = [];

    $scope.scan_code = function(){
        console.log("scan function reached");
        if (typeof $scope.scan.action != 'undefined') {
            console.log($scope.scan.action);
        } else  {
            console.log("action not chosen");
            $scope.scan.alert = 'Please choose an action!';
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    };

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(e) {
        QB.authorize().then(function(authorizeResponse) {
            if (authorizeResponse.ticket) {
                console.log("scanning");
            } else {
                QB.nav('login');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here is all of the view:

```
<ion-view view-title="SCAN">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <h2>Warehouse</h2>
        <h4>{{data.warehouse}}</h4>
        <h2>Item Check In/Out</h2>
        <form ng-controller="ScanCtrl">
        <ion-radio name="action" ng-model='scan.action' value="add">Add item to vehicle</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio name="action" ng-model='scan.action' value="rem">Remove item from vehicle</ion-radio>
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="scan_code()">Scan</button>
        </form>
        <ion-item>
            <p class="assertive">{{scan.alert}}</p>
            <h2>{{data.scannedItems.model_details}}</h2>
            <p>{{data.scannedItems.classification_details}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: It's working fine [in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mc21jHJBahs9P944HYU3?p=preview). Are you getting errors? You need to escape the apostrophe in 'doesn't', btw.

Comment: Sorry, the "doesn't" wasn't there, it actually says "Please choose an action!" the escape shouldn't matter

Comment: what was the error you got with `$scope.apply` ?

Comment: So, there must be something else in your code you're not showing, or some kind of error. I assume you aren't getting a dependency-injection error from `QB`, which you are probably using outside this example.

Comment: @Shri the error i get is Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: @BennettAdams I added the rest of the code in case you see something I don't.

Comment: $scope.$apply is not needed as it is already in digest cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your controller's scope is the `<form>...</form>` element, and you are placing your alert outside of that scope in the template.

Either move the `<p>` element with your alert up within the form, or place the ng-controller attribute on a parent node that includes it.

Please see [the plunker with your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/mc21jHJBahs9P944HYU3?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.controller('ScanCtrl', function($scope, QB){
    $scope.working = 'this update works';
    $scope.method = function(){
        $scope.alert = "this one doesn't";
    }; 
});
```

Note: Either escape `'` like this `\'` or enclose the entire string in double quotes `"this one doesn't"`

EDIT:

considering your code after your edited question,

the problem is with the scope. scope of your controller `ScanCtrl` is within `form` element. Try moving `<ion-item>` inside `form` element this way:

```
<form ng-controller="ScanCtrl">
    <ion-radio name="action" ng-model='scan.action' value="add">Add item to vehicle</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio name="action" ng-model='scan.action' value="rem">Remove item from vehicle</ion-radio>
    <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-  click="scan_code()">Scan</button>
    <ion-item>
        <p class="assertive">{{scan.alert}}</p>
        <h2>{{data.scannedItems.model_details}}</h2>
        <p>{{data.scannedItems.classification_details}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

Or only move `p` element inside `form` and keep rest as it is.

That should solve your problem